# Headings in lists

Tags: html, html-lists

I found this link
[How to semantically add heading to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935262/how-to-semantically-add-heading-to-a-list)

And my problem is in this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>Pepsi</li>
        <li>Cola
            <ol type="a">
                <li>Drink1</li>
                <li>Drink2</li>
                <li>Drink3</li>
            </ol>
        
        </li>
        <li>Fanta</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

I meant to put Cola as a Heading, but I don't know if it is right.
I saw on the link that they say that its ok just to put heading over `ol` or `ul`, and to put it in a `DIV` if you want it all to be together just in case,
but this is another matter because it is a list in a list. There is also a closing tag `</li>` after drinks, and it goes out OK, works just fine...
So I don't know if it is correct, do I need a caption, or just put heading tags or what?

So tell me what is the proper way to put a name for the number 2 `LI`?

Comment: Question is is this code OK?It works fine but looks weird..

Comment: I would use a [description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) instead.  Here's an example of it with heading and multiple dd below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935262/how-to-semantically-add-heading-to-a-list#answer-14338221