# Should I use <li> with empty content as a divider in <ul>?

Tags: html, html-lists

I'm making an user list, and it looks like this

```
User A
User B
--
User C
User D
```

and I wrote my HTML like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>User A</li>
    <li>User B</li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>User C</li>
    <li>User D</li>
</ul>
```

Should I care about if SEO or some crawlers get an empty `<li>` content or not?

Answer (score 4):

After I read [How do I semantically group a header with a UL in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417891/how-do-i-semantically-group-a-header-with-a-ul-in-html)

and [How to semantically add heading to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935262/how-to-semantically-add-heading-to-a-list)

I realized that I should write my HTML in this way:

```
<ul>
    <li>User A</li>
    <li>User B</li>
</ul>
<div class="divider"></div>
<ul>
    <li>User C</li>
    <li>User D</li>
</ul>
```

Or

```
<ul>
    <li>User A</li>
    <li>User B</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<ul>
    <li>User C</li>
    <li>User D</li>
</ul>
```

Not sure if I should keep this question open or not.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, you are creating 2 lists, when you only want one list with a divider in a middle, CSS can do that by itself

Comment: I generally use <li><hr /></li> for a separator, that way it should still look ok without css

Comment: I'm just thinking about should I separate them into 2 lists already or not, since I decided to make a divider in the middle of them ..

Answer (score -2):

Use this. It will be correctly.

```
<ul>
<li>User A</li>
<li>User B</li>
<li class="divider">&nbsp</li>
<li>User C</li>
<li>User D</li>
```